# Is there any way to access .couch files with other owner and group set on the couchdb files?

Tags: linux, couchdb, rhel7

Let's say I have my .couch in some directory A (owner x group x). But I want to use this particular directory as the database_dir of CouchDB. But as soon as I use the directory A as database directory the CouchDB fails to start. Is there any way I can allow read and write access to the .couch files in the directory A to the CouchDB user?

Comment: You may find the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) stacks as a better place to ask this question.